# why java HashMap class has << Left Shift operator for variable declaration

Tags: java

in HashMap.Java file variable is declared like this

```
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4;
```

why not

```
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16
```

is it due to performance or just to show that we are using this as the power of 2?

Comment: It is just to show that the number is a power of two. It does not affect performance.

Comment: There's no performance benefit to using one compile-time constant expression over another.